# How to find magnitude and direction from sum of vectors?

Tags: physics

I have a problem similar to : http://physics.mercer.edu/balduz/GenPhys/HRW7probs/03vectors/3-048.pdf

If A = 10i and 1.63j, what's the next step to finding magnitude and direction? Does it involve multiplying sin/cos? In what combo? What about tan inverse?

Comment: Standard hints for dealing with vectors: (1) Break into components. (2) Draw a picture. (3) Make one or more right triangles. (4) Pythagorean theorem and soh-cah-toa.

Comment: Is direction found by y/x times tan inverse? That isn't working with my homework problem. I don't understand why. http://imgur.com/a/dMTOd

Comment: Do you mean $\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$?  If so, you should know that $\arctan$ only really works in the $1$st and $4$th quadrants.  In the $2$nd and $3$rd you have to add $\pi$ (or $180$ if you're working in degrees) to whatever answer your calculator gives you.

Comment: I have to add 3.14?

Comment: Okay. It worked. Thanks.

Comment: [KhanAcademy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry/trig-equations-and-identities/inverse-trig-functions/v/inverse-trig-functions-arctan) has an explanation for why you need to add $\pi$.